# value read is not a member of org.apache.spark.SparkContext

Tags: scala, apache-spark

The version of scala is 2.11.8 ; jdk is 1.8 ; spark is 2.0.2

I try to run an example of LDA model in [the offical site of spark apache](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-clustering.html#latent-dirichlet-allocation-lda), I got error message from following sentence:

```
val dataset = spark.read.format("libsvm")
  .load("data/libsvm_data.txt")
```

The error massage is:

> Error:(49, 25) value read is not a member of org.apache.spark.SparkContext
>       val dataset = spark.read.format("libsvm")
>                           ^

[image]

I don't know how to solve it.

Answer (score 8):

Looks like you're trying to call `read` on a `SparkContext`, instead of an `SQLContext` or a `SparkSession`:

```
// New 2.0.+ API: create SparkSession and use it for all purposes:
val session = SparkSession.builder().appName("test").master("local").getOrCreate()
session.read.load("/file") // OK

// Old <= 1.6.* API: create SparkContext, then create a SQLContext for DataFrame API usage:
val sc = new SparkContext("local", "test") // used for RDD operations only
val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc) // used for DataFrame / DataSet APIs

sqlContext.read.load("/file") // OK
sc.read.load("/file") // NOT OK
```

Comment: Almost near the answer,
but there needs a bit more refinmend in your asnwer 
I tried and got the following   scala> val session = SparkSession.builder().appName("test").master("local").getOrCreate()
<console>:30: error: not found: value SparkSession
       val session = SparkSession.builder().appName("test").master("local").getOrCreate()

Comment: Not sure I understand. But perhaps you're missing the relevant import? `import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession`

Answer (score 2):

Add these lines:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

val session = SparkSession.builder().appName("app_name").master("local").getOrCreate()

val training = session.read.format("format_name").load("path_to_file")
```

Answer (score 0):

The full syntax for the sqlcontext function is as below

```
val df = sqlContext
                .read()
                .format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
                .option("inferScheme","true")
                .option("header","true")
                .load("path to/data.csv");
```

in case you are reading/writing csv file